# Linq issue select Sum of one column minus another from different table

Tags: c#, .net, linq

This is my sql code

```
SELECT   M.PartNo AS ModulePartNo,
(SELECT SUM(Delivered - Allocated) 
FROM V_InStock Stk
WHERE Stk.PartNo = M.PartNo) AS Available
FROM V_Products M
WHERE M.PartNo='100-25897'
```

I am having real problems getting this to work in Linq, can't work out the sum part - any help would be really appreciated

Comment: I doubt this is valid SQL. Where is M? Whats with this : `), 0) AS Available`?

Comment: Corrected the sql - cut & paste problems (sigh)

Comment: Are there several rows per PartNo in V_InStock?

Comment: Is this VB, C# or is either fine?

Comment: Yes - multiple rows in V_InStock - preferably c# thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
var query = from stk in V_InStock
            group stk by stk.PartNo into stkg
            where stkg.Key == '100-25897'
            select new
            {
              ModulePartNo = stkg.Key,
              Available = stkg.Sum(s => s.Delivered) - stkg.Sum(s => s.Allocated)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do aggregate grouping etc you will probably need to set up an object to "select" everything into. However for a straight join something like this should work.

```
  var outputObject = (from t1 in dbContext.table1
  join t2 in dbContext.table2 on t1.PartNo equals t2.PartNo
  select (t1.Delivered - t2.Allocated));
```

Comment: Thanks - not quite what I need. V_Stock contains parts delivered and allocated from a delivery. There are many deliveries & the fields needs to show how many of a certain part are still available in total